# MERN application on Heroku, missing build script error

Tags: node.js, reactjs, heroku

I'm trying to load a MERN application on Heroku. When trying to do this, however, I get a message from Heroku that the script ***'build'*** was not found. If I switch to the frontend directory with *heroku run bash* and execute the *dir* command there, it is empty. I've already changed the *npm run build* command to *npm run-script*. Then everything is uploaded without errors, but when I call up the page I get the error that the index.html file cannot be found.
My gitignore doesn't contain /build

Folder strucutre:

[image]

package.json:

```
{
"name": "api",
"version": "1.0.0",
"description": "",
"main": "index.js",
"type": "module",
"scripts": {
 "start": "node index.js",  
 "heroku-postbuild": "cd frontend && npm install && npm run build"
},
 "engines": {
  "node": "18.x",
  "npm":"9.x"
 }  
}
```

index.js:

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "frontend/build")));

app.get("*", (req, res) => {
 res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, "frontend/build", "index.html"));
});
```

Comment: For starters, can you confirm there is a "build" folder inside of the "frontend" folder?

Comment: @Sam Levine the frontend folder has no build folder. This should be created by the postbuild expression

Comment: Maybe i'm misunderstanding, but maybe the heroku-postbuild command is not be running properly. Did you try creating the build file and manually dropping it into the frontend folder and see if that works?

Comment: Yes, I've tried that too. But without success. The problem is that Heroku doesn't fill the frontend folder, I can see that using the heroku bash console. The 'dir' command doesn't show me any files/folders inside the folder. So my server is hosted, but the postbuild command is not executed

Comment: Try changing the heroku-postbuild -> build. I don't think you need the postbuild for your case.. If that doesn't work, that's all I've got for you :(